# Any tips on how to make this a method

Tags: c#, methods, simplify

I'm programming a periodic table and currently just programming every button. Now I would like to turn this into a method and just past into every button, I have no idea how to do this though.

```
public void Formule()
    {
        txt_Chemical.Text = h + li + na + k + rb + cs + fr;
    }

    private void btn_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        H++;
        h = "H";
        Formule();

        if (H > 1)
        {
            h = "";
            h = "H" + H;            
            Formule();
        }

    }

    private void btn_Li_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Li++;
        li = "Li";
        Formule();
        if (Li > 1)
        {
            li = "";
            li = "Li" + Li;
            Formule();
        }

    }
```

I would like to put as much of the code in the button into a method any ideas?

Comment: Well, this would better suit [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but you could remove both calls to `Formule()` and place only one at the end of the btn methods (after the `if`, outside the `if`)

Comment: Instead of making a separate variable for every element, consider making an array or list of elements.

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor, and start using meaningful names for your variables. You'll thank me 6 months from now.

Comment: You can identify the individual buttons by checking the `sender` and deduce the element it represents. Maybe consider creating a DataTable for your elements and bind the to a DataGrid having buttons as cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is first - as I wrote in my comment:
Do yourself a huge favor, and start using meaningful names for your variables. You'll thank me 6 months from now.
I simply cannot stress out how important that is.

Now that that's out of the way, let's see how we can simplify this code.

The first thing I've noticed is that the code for each button click can be simplified significantly by using a simple ternary condition instead of your cumbersome code, like this:

This code segment:

```
H++;
h = "H";
Formule();

if (H > 1)
{
    h = "";
    h = "H" + H;            
    Formule();
}
```

Can be converted to this:

```
H++;
h = (H > 1) ? "H" + H : "H";
Formule();
```

Same way, this code segment:

```
Li++;
li = "Li";
Formule();
if (Li > 1)
{
    li = "";
    li = "Li" + Li;
    Formule();
}
```

Can be converted to this:

```
Li++;
li = (Li > 1) ? "Li" + Li : "Li";
Formule();
```

Now, looking at these two segments code, basically I see the same operation being executed on different variables (presumably fields) - when the only difference is the string value.

A generalized function could be something like this:

```
void ReCalculate(string name, ref int field, ref string textField)
{
    field++;
    textField = (field > 1) ? name + field : field;
    txt_Chemical.Text = h + li + na + k + rb + cs + fr;
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
private void btn_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReCalculate("H", ref H, ref h);
}

private void btn_Li_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReCalculate("Li", ref Li, ref li);
}
```

That being said, this is probably not the best way to do it, but the question is lacking a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I had to work with what little knowledge I have about your actual program.

Comment: Shouldn't `void ReCalculate(string name, ref field, ref textField)` be `void ReCalculate(string name, ref int field, ref string textField)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just an example of what could be done with a `Dictionary`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string,int> Values {get;set;}

    static void Main()
    {
        Values = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        Values["Li"] = 1;
        Values["H"] = 1;

        Click("Li"); // displays Li2 H1
        Click("H");  // displays Li2 H2
    }

    static void Click(string element)
    {
        Values[element]++;

        DisplayElements();
    }

    static void DisplayElements()
    {
        foreach(var v in Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Key + v.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, please consider that:

```
private void btn_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    H++;
    h = "H";
    Formule();

    if (H > 1)
    {
        h = "";
        h = "H" + H;            
        Formule();
    }
}
```

Could be written:

```
private void btn_H_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    H++;
    h = "H";

    if (H > 1)
    {
        h += H;
    }
    Formule();
}
```